# How can I typeset in landscape in PlainTeX

Tags: pdftex, okular

I would like to have output turned 90 degrees so I could print envelopes and spread sheets. I use TeX (not LaTeX) and ocular on linux.

Comment: This question has already been answered. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147504/how-to-make-a-latex-document-in-landscape).

Comment: @Raven, the OP is not using latex. Try https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127122/page-layout-in-plain-tex

Comment: I do not use LaTeX. TeX has all I need or want.
But to go landscape the font also need to be turned 90 degrees, not only the paper size.